# MySql va muy lento con Wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, windows, apache, vps

Tengo una página web wordpress en una instancia EC2 de Amazon y aparte una base de datos MySQL Rds en mismo amazon (1vPCU, 1GB ram). Con el objetivo de bajar costos contraté un VPS Windows e instalé mysql para migrar desde amazon a este VPS (Windows Server 2022, 12 vCPU's / 16 GB, 50 gb almacenamiento) Todo iba bien hasta que realice la conexión desde wordpress a este nuevo servidor, ya que el sitio se puso muy lento, se demora 5-10 segundos para pasar de una página a otra cosa que no ocurre con la base de datos original ¿Hay algún tipo de configuración que pueda realizar? edité el my.ini pero no tuve mucho éxito. Quizás el servidor no me sirve ?? Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: decime que segun lo que entendi no instalaste una db con un puerto abierto en otro servidor en otro lado, por lo cual tenes un servidor de db abierto al publico...

Comment: Convendría que revises los archivos de registro de tu servidor, es muy probable que informen o den alguna pista de lo que podría estar ocurriendo.

Comment: No se si te ayude pero hay un plugin para ver todas las transacciones entre WP y la DB. Pueda que si lo instalas te ayude a ver que está generando lentitud, cuantas querys, que tipo de querys y cosas así.

Comment: @gbianchi tengo configurado el firewall para que solo mi ip pueda acceder. Tiene alguna recomendación respecto a esto? Quizás no estoy tomando el mejor camino

Comment: no.. la db debe estar por en un DMZ en el mismo lugar que las aplicaciones.. no puede estar en otro lado... y si esta atras de un firewall, mas tiempo de respuesta. y no, no se expone una db a internet, ni atras de un firewall, ni atras de nada. La unica forma de acceder a una db es mediante una app en el mismo lugar que la db... mover la db de wordpress no fue una buena idea. Tal vez, si es wp, necesitas un servidor wp, y no una instancia cloud tan grande...

Comment: estás con wordpress en aws y la vps con mysql en otro lado? eso suele aumentar la latencia. Si están en la misma máquina debes revisar si o si las querys y configuraciones. Quizás en aws tenías algun sistema de caché de base de datos que en el vps no.